# Is it correct to speak of an object as "cover" ? or to say "behind cover"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

In gunfights, fighters protect themselves from shots by staying behind objects.  It's called *taking cover* and *staying behind cover*.

But cover, just like shadow, is the consequence of the position of two things (persons or light and a person) in relation to a third one (tree).

So because both are limited in time and space, I would tend to consider them more as concepts than objects. However, in my mind, a shelter is definitely an object.

Comment: What is the question here? All of the examples seem correct.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking either.

Answer (score 2):

There are three related meanings for "cover" here. You can use "cover" to indicate:

- the object providing protection (a big rock, say).
- the protected place behind the object (its "shadow").
- the state of being protected (like "being in shadow").

I think the third sense is used only as part of a prepositional phrase ("Bad Bart couldn't shoot me because I was behind cover.")

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> Is it correct to speak of an object as “cover” ? or to say “behind cover” ?

Yes, it is correct to speak of an object as cover. Trees, rocks, are used as a cover,Although, "cover" is a concept, it can also refer to an object, i.e. Something which gives the concept of cover

> There are no trees or rocks on the plain to use as cover

Answer (score 0):

Cover can exist as a potential when not actually in use. So it continues to exist as an object even when not used. For example, someone could view a landscape and say, "Well never see them, there's too much cover." meaning there are too many objects that have the potential of being used as cover.